The whitelist for my smart contract wont work when transacting with uniswap V3 LPs
I am trying to launch a memetoken, but I can't get the whitelist to work.
When transferring between whitelisted addresses, it works as intended: it locks out none-whitelist addresses, and lets whitelisted addresses transact.
However, when a whitelisted addresses tries to transact with the LP i created on Uniswap V3, the swap keeps failing.
I have added the uniswap V3 router, and the address of the liquidity pair to the whitelist, along with the deployment addresses and all whitelist addresses, but it still won't work.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!
